# Can't seem to call NSInvocationOperation with an NSArray

Tags: iphone, uiimage, nsoperationqueue, nsinvocationoperation

I am trying to load an image in the background from a url. The code works great if all I pass is the NSUrl. If I try to pass an NSArray with additional variables, it never gets called:

This code works great, LoadImage2 is called which in turn nicely calls ImageLoaded2.

```
- (void)LoadBackgroundImage2: (char*)pImageURL
{

    NSString* pImageURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", pImageURL];

    NSLog( @"LoadBackgroundImage2: %@", pImageURLString );

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self
                                    selector:@selector(LoadImage2:)
                                    object:pImageURLString];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
}


- (void)LoadImage2: (NSString*)pImageURL
{
    NSLog( @"LoadImage2: %@", pImageURL );

    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pImageURL]];
    UIImage* image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] autorelease];
    [imageData release];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(ImageLoaded2:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

This code does not work. LoadImage never gets called:

```
- (void)LoadBackgroundImage: (char*)pImageURL :(int)textureID :(int)textureType
{

    printf( "LoadBackgroundImage( %s, %d, %d)\n", pImageURL, textureID, textureType );

    NSString* pImageURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", pImageURL];

    NSArray* pUrlAndReferences = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: pImageURLString, textureID, textureType, nil] autorelease];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue new] autorelease];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self
                                    selector:@selector(LoadImage:)
                                    object:pUrlAndReferences];

    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
}


- (void)LoadImage: (NSArray*)pUrlAndReferences
{
    NSString* pImageUrl = [pUrlAndReferences objectAtIndex: 0];
    int textureId = [ [ pUrlAndReferences objectAtIndex: 1 ] intValue ];
    int textureType = [ [ pUrlAndReferences objectAtIndex: 2 ] intValue ];

    NSLog( @"\n\nLoadImage: %@, %d, %d\n", pImageUrl, textureId, textureType );

    NSData* pImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pImageUrl]];
    UIImage* pImage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:pImageData] autorelease];

    NSArray* pImageAndReferences = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: pImage, textureId, textureType, nil] autorelease];

    [pImageData release];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(ImageLoaded:) withObject:pImageAndReferences waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Anyone have any ideas why LoadImage doesn't get called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your not retaining your queue. Here's what's happening

1. Your array (autoreleased) goes into the `NSInvocationOperation` and it's being retained (no problem)
2. Your `NSInvocationOperation` goes into the queue (retained) and then it's released. No problem here since the retain count is still one: 1 (`alloc`) + 1 (`retain`) - 1 (`release`) = 1 = not dealloced.
3. Your queue is alloced (`new` = `alloc`+`init`) and then autoreleased, but it's not being retained elsewhere. Here comes the problem: since you have autoreleased the queue, once the method `LoadBackgroundImage` is finished the queue has a retain count of 0 and it's automatically released, therefore, your Invocation won't be executed.

You can try if that's the problem by just removing the `autorelease` call from the queue. If I'm correct your code should work. But be aware that that is not a good solution because you're loosing memory. It's just to see if it works.

You should definitely make a class, a singleton, an instance variable or whatever you like to retain that instance of the queue. Also, it's a good idea to only have one queue for all the `LoadBackgroundImage` calls instead of creating a new queue every time.